# How can I make a certain row appear even after reload using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

My jquery seems to be working fine. But every time the page refreshes, "row1" just disappears. But the checkbox is still checked.

How can I make "row1" appear even after reload? 
Thank you

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#chk1").click(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#row1").show();
          } else {
            $("#row1").hide();
            $('#tbshow').val("");
          }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="chk1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" value="1" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />Show
</label>

<asp:TableRow ID="row1" runat="server" Style="display: none" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:Label ID="lblshow" runat="server" Text="Show">
    </asp:Label>
  </asp:TableCell>
  <asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbshow" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
  </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: You're hiding the row in the HTML, <asp:TableRow ID="row1" runat="server" Style="display: none" ClientIDMode="Static"> remove the display: none?

Comment: I have realized that but it's still disappearing on every page load :(

Answer (score 0):

I would change your ready function to be:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     if ( $("#chk1").prop("checked") ) {
           $("#row1").show();
       }
        $("#chk1").click(function() {
          if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#row1").show();
          } else {
            $("#row1").hide();
            $('#tbshow').val("");
          }
        });
```